# ValueError at /success Invalid address in django EmailMultiAlternatives

Tags: django

I want sent to multiple email but i got this raise ValueError('Invalid address "%s"' % addr)
ValueError: Invalid address "['ex1@gmail.com', 'ex2@gmail.com', 'ex404@gmail.com']"

```
        email_id = ["ex1@gmail.com","ex2@gmail.com","ex404@gmail.com"]
        username = name
        email = email_id
        ######################### mail system ####################################
        htmly = get_template('email/Email.html')
        d = { 
            's_id' : s_id,
            'username': username, 
            'tran_id' : tran_id,
            'amount'  : amount

            }
        subject, from_email, to = 'welcome', 'your_email@gmail.com', email
        html_content = htmly.render(d)
        msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, html_content, from_email, [to])
        msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
        msg.send()
```

Comment: `to` is already a list of emails, then you place that list in a list. Change `[to]` to `to` on the third row from the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You send array type to an another array, So array dimension was changed.
Please check like this.

```
        email_id = ["ex1@gmail.com","ex2@gmail.com","ex404@gmail.com"]
        username = name
        email = email_id
        ######################### mail system ####################################
        htmly = get_template('email/Email.html')
        d = { 
            's_id' : s_id,
            'username': username, 
            'tran_id' : tran_id,
            'amount'  : amount

            }
        subject, from_email, to = 'welcome', 'your_email@gmail.com', email
        html_content = htmly.render(d)
        msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, html_content, from_email, to)
        msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
        msg.send()
```

Comment: Thanks for full code

Answer (score 0):

As other pointed out, you shouldn't enclose `to` in square brackets because it was already a list of strings, which is exactly what the parameter expects. See this example:

```
msg = EmailMultiAlternatives("subject", html_content, "from@@gmail.com", ["to@@gmail.com", "to2@@gmail.com", "to3@@gmail.com"])
```